# DNS changes automatically to porn site DNS

Tags: dns, malware

I am using OS X Mavericks 10.9.4 and Windows 8.1 with Boot Camp. It is not happening everyday but it happens at least in every 3-4 days. When I log in to 192.168.1.1 and check my DNS they are just some porn sites. I change them to the Google DNS and even tried to change it to Use Auto Discovered DNS Server Only option. Still no luck. I scanned my system with ClamXav and Kaspersky I got nothing.

Comment: Have you tried resetting your router and then quick changing your router username/password?

Comment: Are you saying that the DNS server IP address your router points to also hosts porn?

Comment: In addition to @jayson above, I'd disconnect the router from the WAN before doing that to be extra careful.  You may also turn off "WAN management" to prevent access to the admin area from outside your local network.

Comment: If this does fix it but some of these symptoms come back after hooking back into the WAN, I have had an infected modem before that kept changing my dns settings.

Comment: Before turning off WAN or something I really want to know what causes that.

Comment: You have malware on your home router.